# UIWebview does not start loading

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I'm developing a native application for a website. The application is basically a wrapper around the website, which implements things like push notifications. When a push notification is clicked, the following code is used to go to the appropriate page:

```
- (NSString *)handlePush:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
    if ([[notification objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"]) {
        int badgeNum = [[[notification objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Badge: %i, got from %@", badgeNum, [[notification objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"]);
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNum;
    }
    if (!active) {
        NSLog(@"Got noti while not active, going to that chat!");
        NSString *hash;
        if ((hash = [notification objectForKey:@"h"])) {
            NSLog(@"Hash: %@", [hash stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@", hash];
        }
        return @"";
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Active is changed when the application enters the background and after it resumes, to make sure it does not trigger when a push notification arrives when the user is using the app. 
The URL is parsed properly, because if i manually paste the exact same URL in the browser, i do go to the correct page.

I am 100% certain the delegate is set, as the `UIWebView: ShouldStartLoadWithRequest` method is called:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest called with url %@", url);

    if ([url hasPrefix:BASE_URL]) {
        NSLog(@"Yea, i'll load this one for ya");
        // remove any get-params / hash suffix
        NSRange r = [url rangeOfString:@"?"];
        if (r.location == NSNotFound)
            r = [url rangeOfString:@"#"];

        if (r.location != NSNotFound)
            url = [url substringToIndex:r.location];

        if (![url isEqualToString:[defaults valueForKey:@"baseUrl"]]) {
            NSLog(@"setting new baseUrl %@", url);

            [defaults setValue:url forKey:@"baseUrl"];
            [defaults synchronize];
        }

        NSLog(@"Should go and load it now...");
        return YES;
    } 
}
```

There's some logic for caching versions of the webpage in there. I stepped through with breakpoints, and it reaches the `return YES` part, and the logs in there are called. However, in that same delegate, the `didStartLoad` and `didFailLoadWithError` are not called, which contain purely NSLogs.

On the initial application start, this does work, and it has worded one time too where i stepped through for a long time using the breakpoint, so it seems it's some timing issue. Hoping not having to use any hacky solutions like timers, i was hoping that anyone around here has experience with a similar problem, or has any other valuable input.

Comment: Do you use by any chance more than one UIWebView? In this case, you can get a race condition since the class is not reentrant.

Comment: I'm quite sure it's a race condition seeing the circumstances, but i'm only using one webview... Currently fixed it with a very, very ugly hack to slow down the code enough to avoid it.

Comment: If it works the first time, do you ensure that the next time `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` returns YES, too? Maybe you should add a return value (and a log) for the alternative case: it is in general a bad idea to allow a void return in a BOOL function.

Comment: There's quite a bit more logic in that function that i did not copy there, sorry for not mentioning. It has about 4 more cases for among others some javascript-to-native 'hacks', and defaults with a `return NO`. This part, however, is the only part it reaches in the relevant code.

Comment: Murphy: "In any collection of data, the figures that are obviously correct, beyond all need of checking, contain the errors." ;-)

Comment: Never heard that one, though i have experienced it several times myself. Which is why i actually placed those log statements in that code, and ran a breakpoint walkthrough there ;) It's very likely a problem in another, totally unsuspected part of my code... which is why i was hoping someone else would have an idea :)